# How to fix grumble.js jQuery plugin (Bubble popups) for non white backgrownds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

So [grumble.js](http://jamescryer.github.com/grumble.js/) is a really sweet plugin for crossbrowser bubble looking popups. But it has a really bad bug in it - its bubbles are somehow [cut out](https://github.com/jamescryer/grumble.js) incorrectly So I created a demo: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sR9zG/5/). and here is an image of the problem (latest chrome):

[image: white dots=(]

So I wonder - is it possible to fix such thing and how to do it?

Comment: There's a rotation in the CSS and those dots look like artifacts from the rotation. Have you tried spreading out the sprite images a bit? You'd need to adjust the CSS offsets for the sprites as well of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dots are actually tips of other bubbles in the sprite image. Check out the link to see the whole image: 
https://github.com/jamescryer/grumble.js/raw/master/images/bubble-sprite.png .
If you inspect the bubble with firebug and increase width or height you will see the other bubbles showing up.

You can fix this by editing the sprite image itself (bubble-sprite.png) in an image editing software like Adobe Photoshop or Adobe Fireworks  and increase the space between the bubbles, both horizontally and vertically.